# Equivalence classes when x - y = multiple of 3?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations, relations, equivalence-relations, integers

> R  exactly when  −  equals a multiple of 3.

There exists equivalence classes [0], [1] and [2]. Prove that [1] + [2] is equal to [0].

Not sure about the ambigious part, all I could find from my research was that if it's intepreted different ways the meaning will still be the same e.g. [1] + [2] = [0] is the same as [2] + [1] = [0] or [0] = [2] + [1]. But I am unsure about that.

How do I create these equivalence classes and prove that [1] + [2] is equal to class [0] ?

Comment: The equivalence class [0] consists of all multiples of 3, {..., -6, -3, 0, 3, 6, ...}.  That can also be represented as {3n} where n is any integer.  The equivalence class [1] consists of all numbers that are one more than a multiple of 3, {..., -5, -2, 1, 4, 7, ...}.  That can also be represented as {3n+ 1}.  The equivalence class [2] consists of all numbers that are two more than a multiple of 3, {..., -4, -1, 2, 5, 8, ...}.  That can also be represented as {3n+ 2}.

Answer (score 1):

Here,$$[1]=\{\ldots,-5,-2,1,4,7,\ldots\}=\{3n+1\mid n\in\Bbb Z\}$$and$$\quad[2]=\{\ldots,-4,-1,2,5,8,\ldots\}=\{3n+2\mid n\in\Bbb Z\}.$$And when you add *any* element of $[1]$ to *any* element of $[2]$, you get an element of$$[0]=\{\ldots,-6,-3,0,3,6,\ldots\}=\{3n\mid n\in\Bbb Z\}.$$So, if $m\in[1]$ and $n\in[2]$, the class of $m+n$ is independent of the choice of $m$ and $n$, and therefore $[1]+[2]$ is not ambiguous (and it turns out that it is equal to $[0]$).

Comment: I do not understand what you are asking.